# Apache 2.4 rules, white list ,htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directive

Need to give access to intranet users, but at same time access to a pc that's not on intranet. The below grants access to intranet users, but fails on access to pc not on intranet. How to fix? (The IP address is dynamic. I manually edit it now, but if there is a way to account for it being dynamic, let me know.) The .htaccess file resides on the intranet, if that matters; it might be why it fails in external IPaddress

```
    <RequireAny>
         Require  host  pp.college.edu
         Require ip 999.234.123
    </RequireAny>
```

Comment: This sounds like a networking issue (and off-topic on StackOverflow and not really much to do with `.htaccess` I suspect)? How/where does this PC fit into this network/intranet?

Comment: well..is the directive correct first off? This directive is used in the .htaccess file to prevent anyone outside of the edu hostname/domain from looking at the site. So, the first part works (Require  host  pp.college.edu). Is it possible to reference an IPaddress that is outside the intranet? As the directive is written, no IPaddresses outside the intranet are allowed, but I'd like one outside the intranet to access the site. How do you write that?

Comment: "999.234.123" is not an ip address nor an ip address prefix as recognized by httpd. The only way to allow for a dynamic address to be accomodated by a static config is to use dynamic DNS with PTR records. Even if this were possible, using an IP address as an authentication token sucks.

Comment: The IPaddress was fake; it was meant just to represent an IPaddress. Well, I understand an IPv4 or IPv6 can be used too

Comment: Is there anyway to represent a particular host not on the intranet, does it work by machine name?

Comment: But how does a machine "outside the intranet" even access the network/intranet in the first place? The `Require IP <ip-address>` directive is only relevant if that PC is able to access the network, then the `<ip-address>` is then the IP address that Apache sees when this machine connects.

Comment: Logically this could work.  To debug, put `LogLevel Trace8`.  In your error log you will see a LOT of logs, with a LOT of details.  It should report why it accepts, or not, each request.  I like @MrWhite 's comment, the IP Apache sees as the source IP for the PC might not be the one you expect..

Comment: Which error log are you speaking of? I don't have access to Apache config files. I can read the error log that is setup by system admin, but can't touch any other apache files

Comment: Ok..the server log shows a few errors over and over:[error] mod_authz_core.c(882): [client XX.XXX.XX.XXX] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /server/path/to/root/                           What does it mean or suggest? What needs to be fixed?

Comment: Looking into getting the LogLevel set to LogLevel Trace8 in the conf file. Stay tuned

Comment: Got the log file to LogLevel Trace 8. Thanks for that. Now an issue with application. As soon as it' fixed, will tell you what's in the log

Comment: # BEGIN WordPres
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* – [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ – [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
 The other half of this comment is in the next comment below this one. Can't put them all together

Comment: <RequireAny>
Require all denied
Require ip outside-edu-domain-Ip-address
Require ip outside-edu-domain-Ip-address
Require host school-domain
</RequireAny>
Questions continues in next comment too

Comment: Permissions block needs to deny all except those on the school-domain, but allow only specific IPaddress outside the domain to the site. When I use the above directive, the IPaddresses don’t see the site’s home page. but the Apache server’s default page, “It works”. The system admin says something in the .htaccess file is incorrect and causes that, but only the above directives are in .htaccess file. The first directive is written by Wordpress. Do you see anything wrong (incorrect directive) with this .htaccess file? If not, then what can be causing the Apache "It works" page to be appearing?

Comment: It works! I used LogLevel Trace8 and saw that I used the wrong Ipaddress in the Require Any block. Once I switched Ips, the site's home page was visible from outside the school's domain